# Does steps_per_epoch param of model.fit() function override the value of Sequence's __len__()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

According to the [tf.keras.utils.Sequence](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) official documentation, the general convention to set the return value of `__len__()` function is `training size / batch size`.

This ensures that for a single epoch, your model is trained on the all the training data for once.

**My question -** When we pass the value of `steps_per_epoch` in the `model.fit()` function, does it override the value returned by the `__len__()` function?

Suppose the value of the param `steps_per_epoch` is `x`. And I explicitly pass this param in the `model.fit()` function. Then regardless of what value is returned by the `__len__()` function, for a single epoch, will the model be trained on `x` * `batch_size` number of samples?

Answer (score 0):

yes if you set the batch_size and the steps_per_epoch only these amount of data points will be used before an epoch is ended. This can be used for e.g. on tensorflow dataset iterators which don't have an end because there are set into an inf loop with .repeat(). Here the there would be no end and the epoch would go on for ever. To change this you can set the steps per epoch. Normally an epoch should be trained on the whole dataset before doing a validation step so it usually is good to not set it manually unless you have to.